# Implement undelivered messages with anycable Gem and server anycablego

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, actioncable

I want to implement something like whatsapp message, when you are not connected and you are connected again your message is arrived. but for that I implement after_subscribe the callback method **forwading_queues** than is executed after subscription channel. The problem is when there was some disconnection from client, and quickly he is connected again the method **forwading_queues** is executed but no send broadcast, I think that is because the old connection is active yet and the broadcast is send to old connection, because sometimes after the server said THE USER WAS DISCONNECTED but the **broadcast_to** was already executed in the method **forwading_queues**

```
class UserChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
 after_subscribe :forwading_queues
 def subscribed
  stream_for current_user
 end

 def forwading_queues
  UserChannel.broadcast_to current_user, {message: 'You are back!'}
 end
end
```

Do you know what is happening here ?

Comment: I am not 100% sure why it happens but you could use `trasmit` and send directly message without going into pubsub

Comment: Ok thanks I will try it.